# Pulling two lists into one, and showing duplicates

Tags: excel

I know it's possible to have lists referenced and show an answer, but is it possible to do so with duplicates, and showing said duplicates?

Attached is a file, all I need to do is reference the ID, and show said duplicates and where they are.

I could use something like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Jobs List'!$F:$F,MATCH(1,INDEX(('Jobs List'!$B:$B=$AG$3)*('Jobs List'!$B:$B=$AG$3),0),0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Archive!$F:$F,MATCH(1,INDEX((Archive!$B:$B=$AG$3)*(Archive!$B:$B=$AG$3),0),0)),""))
```

But the problem is it should show only the first duplicate and ignore the rest.

I know it's possible, I just don't have the skills to do so.  If someone can help It be appreciated.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Multiple%20answers%20one%20chart.xlsx

Comment: Your sample sheet doesn't match your sample formula.  A good sample sheet gives BEFORE / AFTER examples, manually mockup the results you expect and point out the cells you're trying to automate if it's not obvious.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think about that, but basically I figured my explanation would be enough. The link was updated to show what you want.

Comment: It might have been, normally, but notice even you changed the layout of your sheet when asked to mock the results up manually?  Answer posted below.

Comment: I did that so that if scripts needed to be added next to each section no one would need to move anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it with some help... and an old script I had:

**B7**: `=IFERROR(INDEX(F$8:F$11,MATCH(ROWS(B$7:B7),$H$8:$H$11,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(J$8:J$11,MATCH(ROWS(B$7:B7),$L$8:$L$11,0)),""))`

**C7**`=IF(B7="","",$C$2)`

**F7**`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROWS(D$7:D7),$H$8:$H$11,0)),$F$6,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROWS(D$7:D7),$L$8:$L$11,0)),$J$6,""))`

Drag down. This works. I had some help on a forum, but Jerry's response also helped as well.  Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

The formulas would be:

B7 (array): **=IFERROR(INDEX($G$4:$G$7, SMALL(IF($H$4:$H$7=$C$2, ROW($G$4:$G$7)-3, ""), ROW(A1))), INDEX($J$4:$J$7, SMALL(IF($K$4:$K$7=$C$2, ROW($J$4:$J$7)-3, ""), ROW(A1)-COUNTIF($H$4:$H$7, $C$2))))**

C7: **=IF(B7="", "", $C$2)**

D7: **=IF(B7="","",IF(ROW(A1)>COUNTIF($H$4:$H$7,$C$2),$J$2,$G$2))**

Copy those 3 cells downward.

Comment: It didn't work. It came back with a #NUM error.  I think I see what you are doing, but it's not working...The link has been updated: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Open%20Order%20Report%20v2.xlsm

Comment: What didn't work?  Where is your version of my formula in that workbook?  #NUM is a common error when you take a formula like mine that refers to a specific number of rows and try to apply it to an entire column.  That first formula is an array, you don't want millions of calcs in one cell... so don't do that.

Comment: As Jerry implicitly pointed out, an array formula cannot accept an entire column as input, so limit your range.

Comment: I solved it pulling a few tricks out of my hat, and also referencing some old code I had... check the workbook now.